# Does np.array's astype prevent future edits in DataFrames?

Tags: numpy, dataframe, pandas

I can change the first entry of the DataFrame initially:

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2))
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
          0         1
0  0.514592  0.459589
1  0.329704  0.409099
2  0.061246  0.966191
3  0.336747  0.908513
4  0.169220  0.468437

In [8]: df.ix[0][0] = 1
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
          0         1
0  1.000000  0.459589
1  0.329704  0.409099
2  0.061246  0.966191
3  0.336747  0.908513
4  0.169220  0.468437
```

But after I do this:

```
In [10]: df[0] = np.floor(df.index / 10).astype(int) * 10
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   0         1
0  0  0.459589
1  0  0.409099
2  0  0.966191
3  0  0.908513
4  0  0.468437
```

I can't find a way to change it.

```
In [12]: df.ix[0][0] = 1
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   0         1
0  0  0.459589
1  0  0.409099
2  0  0.966191
3  0  0.908513
4  0  0.468437
```

And I can't even change elements from other columns

```
In [16]: df.ix[0][1] = 1

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   0         1
0  0  0.459589
1  0  0.409099
2  0  0.966191
3  0  0.908513
4  0  0.468437
```

What's up with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are editing a copy, try

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2))

In [4]: df[0] = np.floor(df.index / 10).astype(int) * 10

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   0         1
0  0  0.201611
1  0  0.390364
2  0  0.727422
3  0  0.941035
4  0  0.036764

In [6]: df.ix[0,1] = 1

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   0         1
0  0  1.000000
1  0  0.390364
2  0  0.727422
3  0  0.941035
4  0  0.036764
```

Comment: Interesting, so is `.ix` the only way of changing it? And do you know why accessing the column with `[colname]` separately only gives a copy?

Comment: ``[]`` slices the rows in a DataFrame, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#basics, the colname access is a convenience feature, that returns the underlying series as a copy, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#copying

Comment: But why does colname access change `df` with inputs 8 and 10, before the `astype` assignment, if colname access only returns a copy, but doesn't change `df` after that (inputs 12 & 16)?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it just depends on whatever numpy wants to do http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: ``.ix`` will return a view or a copy, *depending on numpy*, which means practially, the layout in memory is the issue. before the astype, this was a single dtype, so a single block of memory, so you get a view, after the astype, somethings are copied (by numpy), so you can no longer get a view, so you get a copy, weird, but it doesn't provide 'guarantees'. If you use the ``ix[row,col] = value`` syntax you can avoid this whole issue (or in 0.11, ``loc[row,col]`` and ``iloc[row_number,col_number]``. HTH